# can i raise exception from inside a function in the 'try:' block when client disconnects from the server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, return-value, try-except

im trying to build a simple server-client chatroom with python socket.

i have the following code:

```
def handle_connection(client):
    while(1):
        try:
            message = receive_message()
            broadcast(message["data"])
        except:     # for now i don't mind which exception
              print("client disconnected")


def receive_message(client_socket):
    try:
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER)
        if len(message_header) == 0:
            return False
        message_length = int(message_header.decode("utf-8"))

        message = client_socket.recv(message_length).decode("utf-8")
        return {"header": message_header, "data": message}

    except:  # most likely will trigger when a client disconnects
        return False
```

where `receive_message()` calls inside of it to `client.recv(HEADER)` and returns either `False` when there is no message, or `{"header": msg_header, "data": msg}` when everything is ok.

my question is: if `client.recv()` fails inside of `receive_message()` due to the client CLI closing, will it raise the exception and print `"client disconnected"`, or not?

i did come up with the following solution i think works:

i defined a function called `handle_disconnection()` that handles all the content inside of the `except` in the code above.

```
def handle_connection(client_socket):
    while 1:
        try:
            message = receive_message()
            if not message:
                handle_disconnection(client_socket)
                break
            broadcast(message["data"])

        except:     # client disconnected
            handle_disconnection(client_socket)
            break
```

is this a valid and/or right programming approach to the problem?
if this approach is wrong, how can i handle it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `client.recv()` will raise an exception you will handle it inside of `receive_message()`  and `handle_connection()` will not receive the exception.

I suggest you to identify situations when you want to control the flow with exceptions or with if-else. I think `receive_message()` should return a value of message or throw `ConnectionError` when there are connection issues. In case when there are no messages from the socket you can return `None` or raise `NoMessagesAvailableError`.

There is also a rule that tells you should catch specified exceptions, not all of them. Your code will print `client disconnected` when you are out of memory.